# Export observer pattern from a c++ library in c code

Tags: c++, c, observer-pattern

I have a c++ shared library that can generate some event. I've an interface for the listener and a class that is able to register observers and fire events.

This library may be used used from java, C# and C++ code( compiled with differenc compilers) so I've two file headers: *.h for ANSI C interface and *.hpp for use library directly from C++ code. Now I cannot figure how export observer pattern with a C-like interface.

Here is a little snippet of how code is structured.

```
// hpp file
class IListener
{
public:
    virtual ~IListener() {}

    virtual void event1( int ) = 0;
    virtual void event2() = 0;
};

using IListenerPtr = std::shared_ptr< IListener >;

class Controller
{
public:
    Controller( IListenerPtr listener );

    void addListener( IListenerPtr listener );

private:
    void threadFunc()
    {
        while ( true )
        {
            // an event occured

            for ( auto& e : mListeners )
                e->event1( 2 );

            for ( auto& e : mListeners )
                e->event2();
        }
    }


private:
    std::vector< IListenerPtr > mListeners;

};

// h file

#if defined( __MSCVER ) || defined( __MINGW32__ ) || defined( __MINGW64__ )
#   define LIB_CALLBACK __stdcall
#   define LIB_CALL __cdecl
#   if defined( AAMS_EXPORTS )
#       define LIB_API __declspec( dllexport )
#   else
#       define LIB_API __declspec( dllimport )
#   endif
#else
#   define LIB_API
#endif // WIN32

typedef int libError;

LIB_API libError LIB_CALL libInit( ???? );
```

How can I make this library usable from C code? A first attempt maybe:

```
typedef struct libListenerTag
{
    typedef void (LIB_CALLBACK *Event1Func)( int );
    typedef void (LIB_CALLBACK *Event2Func)();

    Event1Func Event1;
    Event2Func Event2;

} libListener;

LIB_API libError LIB_CALL libInit( libListener* listener );
```

and in someway bind `libListener` to `IListener`

```
// cpp file
class CListener : public IListener
{
public:
    CListener( libListener* listener 
        : mListener( listener )
    {
    }

    void event1( int i ) { mListener->Event1( i ); }
    void event2() {  mListener->Event12(); }

private:
    libListener* mListener;
}

Controller* g_controller = nullptr;

LIB_API libError LIB_CALL libInit( libListener* listener )
{
    g_controller = new Controller( make_shared< CListener >( listener ); 

    // ...
}
```

This method doesn't look very good for me. Is a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing something that's standard in C event callbacks: a context pointer.

In C++ your `IListener` subclass gets an implicit `this` pointer in its callbacks, meaning it can store state and context info in the instance.

For free functions, you don't have this, so you need to add an explicit argument.

```
/* c_interface.h */
typedef void (*EventCallback1)(void *context, int arg);
typedef void (*EventCallback2)(void *context);

struct Listener; /* opaque type */

struct Listener *create_listener(EventCallback1, EventCallback2, void *context);
void destroy_listener(struct Listener*);
```

so from the C side, you pack whatever state you need into a structure, pass it into `create_listener` as your context, and get it passed back to your functions when they're called.

```
// c_implementation.cpp
extern "C" {
#include "c_interface.h"

struct Listener: public IListener {
  EventCallback1 cb1;
  EventCallback2 cb2;
  void *context;

  Listener(EventCallback1 e1, EventCallback2 e2, void *c)
    : cb1(e1), cb2(e2), context(c)
  {}

  virtual void event1(int arg) {
    (*cb1)(context, arg);
  }
  virtual void event2() {
    (*cb2)(context);
  }
};

Listener *create_listener(EventCallback1 cb1, EventCallback2 cb2, void *context) {
    return new Listener(cb1, cb2, context);
}
}
```

The client code looks something like

```
#include "c_interface.h"

struct MyContext {
    int things;
    double needed;
    int to_handle;
    char callbacks[42];
};

void cb0(void *context) {}
void cb1(void *context, int arg) {
    struct MyContext *c = (struct MyContext *)context;
    c->things = arg;
}

void foo() {
    struct MyContext *context = malloc(sizeof(*context));
    struct Listener *l = create_listener(cb1, cb0, context);
    ...
```